# How to emit event that changes css styles

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to make an `eventBus` in the `App.vue` component that can be called from anywhere in my app and changes a modal's CSS based on a payload as an object. If I pass `{ type: 'success' }` it should change the border to green, if I pass `{ type: 'danger' }` it should make it red. Example call:

```
 EventBus.$emit('call-modal', { type:'success' });
```

I keep my modal styles in the parent as objects, but don't know how to change the CSS based on the payload, so how can I achieve this CSS change with the `eventBus`?

Gere is my sample component:

```
<template>
  <div>
   <button class="pleeease-click-me" @click="callModal()">Click me</button>
   <div class="modal" v-show="showModal">
     <h2>Messsage</h2>
   </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { EventBus } from '../App.vue';

export default {
  name: 'bankAccount',
  props: ['modalType'],
  data() {
    return {
      showModal: false
    }
  },
   methods: {
    callModal() {
      this.showModal = !this.showModal
      // Send the event on a channel (i-got-clicked) with a payload (the click count.)
      EventBus.$emit('call-modal', {type:'success'});
    }
  }
}

</script>

<style scoped>

.modal {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: solid gray 2px;
}
</style>
```

And my App.vue component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

  <bankAccount/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import bankAccount from './components/bankAccount.vue'
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();


EventBus.$on('call-modal', (type) => {

})

export default {
  data() {
   modalTypes = [
     { type: 'success' },
     { type: 'danger' },
   ]
  },
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    bankAccount
  },
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off drop your modal component directly in `App.vue`. Also define data properties such as `showModal` and `modalType` that will contain data about the modal. In `created` hook just watch `call-modal` events, and change local data properties. Don't forget to bind appropriate class depending on `modalType` value. That's it.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <bankAccount />
    <div :class="['modal', `modal--type--${modalType}`]" v-show="showModal">
      <h2>Messsage</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import bankAccount from './components/bankAccount.vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
export const EventBus = new Vue()

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    bankAccount,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showModal: false,
      modalType: 'default',
    }
  },
  created() {
    EventBus.$on('call-modal', obj => {
      this.showModal = true
      this.modalType = obj.type
    })
  },
}
</script>

<style>
.modal {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: solid gray 2px;
}

.modal--type--success {
  border-color: green;
}
</style>
```

To open modal just emit `'call-modal'` event through `EventBus`.

```js
EventBus.$emit('call-modal', { type: 'success' });
```

Comment: Thanks, added you code to the App.vue, but how do I make the call for the success class?

Comment: `EventBus.$emit('call-modal', 'success');` if you want, I can edit the answer to accept the object with `type` property.

Comment: any idea how can I make this work also by calling it with this.$root.$emit instead?

Answer (score 0):

You have to register, deregister the `EventBus` in your components.

It can be done via `Vue.mixin` for all components or via `import` in a single one:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

  <bankAccount :class="modalTypes"/>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import bankAccount from './components/bankAccount.vue'
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();


EventBus.$on('call-modal', (type) => {

})

export default {
  data() {
   return {
     modalTypes = {
       'success': false,
       'danger': false
     }
   }
  },
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    bankAccount
  },
  created(){
    EventBus.$on('call-modal', this.callModal)
  },
  beforeDestroy(){
    EventBus.$off('call-modal', this.callModal)
  },
  methods: {
    callModal(evt){
      for(let key in this.modalTypes) 
        this.modalTypes[key] = key === evt.type
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: hmm it gives me  Property or method "modalTypes" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render and "ReferenceError: modalTypes is not defined" and doesn't work

Comment: @MahmaDeva oh yeah typo - data() { return ... }